# Interpreting Pointers w/ Structs In C Linked Lists

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

Edit: the structs are as follows ...

```
typedef struct node
{
    student* student;
    struct node* next;

}node;
```

And ...

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char* name;
    char* house;
}student;
```

I'm trying to interpret the following code involving pointers to structs in a linked list and deleting that list. Here's how I am thinking about this, and I know something is wrong. Two lines in particular are troubling me.  First, `node* ptr = first`.  This should hold the address of `node* first = NULL`.  Since first is already set to NULL, it also seems to hold NULL, based on how it is used. In other words, does `node* ptr = first` mean `ptr` holds both the address **and** contents of `first`? I thought it would be only the address. Similarly, does `node* predptr = ptr` indicate `predptr` holds not just the address, but everything that `ptr` was pointing to? It would seem so because `predptr->student != NULL` is acting like a struct (not just a holding tank for the address of one) through which you can access data held in `ptr`, though no explicit dereferencing has occurred anywhere in the code snippet.  Could someone tell me where my interpretation is off? I think it all boils down to whether or not these pointers are carrying just addresses (that need to be dereferenced to access actual values) or enabling access to values with requiring explicit dereferencing. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
// free list before quitting
node* ptr = first;
while (ptr != NULL);
{
    node* predptr = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    if (pedptr->student != NULL)
    { etc
```

Comment: give complete code - with struct declaration

Comment: `node* first = NULL; node* ptr = first;` means exactly the same as `int first = 0; int ptr = first;` except that it's NULL instead of 0.

Comment: Your interpretation is off at the part where you think pointers hold structures.

Comment: It would really help if you added more code. The snippet as given does not make it easy to help ie we'd be guessing and that's a waste of time.